# Using R in WPF C#

Tags: c#, r, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I design my user interface in WPF C#, and like to attached some histograms (generated as if it is a R project) on to a WPF Canvas. Is it possible?

Comment: Generate them as image (jpg or vector) and display as such?

Comment: Image is ok, but the data to be processed in R would depend on user interaction in run time with the user interface, which is WPF.  For example, in the WPF application, user select a group of data, then R would process the data and output a histogram, for example. I like to know if that is possible.

Comment: Easiest would be to call your R script after input change, generate image with it and display in WPF.

Comment: The Nuget Library of interest is [R.NET Graphics Engine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET.Community.Graphics/0.2.2-alpha)